# Send data to another xaml in Windows Phone 8.1 - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

How can I get a variable in one xaml(when the button is clicked) to appear in another xaml in a textbox. 
Basically once the button is clicked in Menu.xaml the name variable is displayed in a text box in Basket.xaml. How can I go about doing that?

**Button in Menu.xaml**

```
 Private Sub VanButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles VanButton.Click
    Dim Name As String = "Vanilla"
End Sub
```

**Variable Name into Basket.xaml textbox once button is clicked in Menu.xaml**

```
Private Sub IcecreamChosen_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles IcecreamChosen.TextChanged

End Sub
```

The app is developed in VB.NET , Visual Studios 2015. I am new to this and have no idea on how to make it work this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give a name to your textbox and the in the button click event handle you can write yourtextboxname.Text = variabile

Anyway I suggest you to start using databinding approach. Xaml is databinding based! :)